# Sac Fly or not?

Tags: baseball, scoring

Runners on 1st & 3rd with one out.  Runner on 1st attempts to steal as batter lines out to RF.  runner on 3rd tags and scores before runner attempting to steal is doubled off of 1st.  The run counts. How is the AB scored?  Sac Fly w/RBI or Double Play w/no RBI?

Comment: I believe it's scored the same as a ground ball to ShortStop. A double play with no RBI.

Answer (score 2):

Rule 10.04(b)

> The official scorer shall not credit a run batted in
>
> 1. when the batter grounds into a force double play or a reverse-force double
>      play;

We know what a force out is (a runner is forced out when a fielder with the ball steps on a bag that they are required to advance to). But what is a "reverse-force"

Rule 2.00

> (b) A reverse force double play is one in which the first out is a force play and the
>   second out is made on a runner for whom the force is removed by reason of
>   the first out. Examples of reverse force plays: runner on first, one out; batter
>   grounds to first baseman, who steps on first base (one out) and throws to sec-
>   ond baseman or shortstop for the second out (a tag play)

In other words it's the old force the runner at first, tag the runner going to second play.

This is not the case in the play described, and there is no error on the play so the batter would be credited with a sac fly and an RBI and the runner getting doubled off first base would get a [TOOTBLAN](http://tootblan.tumblr.com/)

All rules citations from [here](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/downloads/y2013/official_baseball_rules.pdf)

Comment: To clarify, because the batter flies out, the play at second is never a force play (the runner on first isn't required to run and in fact must tag up before attempting to advance). Because it's not a force play, the batter didn't hit into a DP; it's a simple flyout. Because he advanced a runner, it's a sac fly, and because the runner advanced home it's a sac RBI.